# Need to mvn clean install everytime I change .java code

Tags: spring, maven

I have a maven based multimodule project of angular and spring boot running in my local machine and whenever I change code of spring boot, I need to run mvn clean install to reflect changes. How do I solve it out. Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Please do research first. You can find lot of code watchers for Java Projects after simple google search. For example, https://github.com/rzymek/watcher-maven-plugin

Comment: tried that one as well but didn't work for me.. Maybe I was unable to describe my issue properly and also going through your suggestion. Hope I find someting

Comment: @Darshana It is only a simple Google search if you know what to search for.  Now that you do, perhaps share the search terms that locates one that will work for OP?

Comment: @SabinShrestha you can use the search term, "Maven | Spring | Gradle Code watchers" - This is a solution to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you change the code in the IDE, you don't really have to run mvn clean install after each and every single change.
Instead you can rely on the IDE that is supposed to maintain the model of the project (created out of pom.xml) when you open the project. The IDE keeps track on the relevant files, that must be recompiled after the changes. Usually its only a small fraction of the whole codebase.

I personally run maven locally after I do significant changes (like before pushing the change upstream).

Even if we do I suggest you to consider the following optimizations:

- you don't have to run the clean install on all the project, instead you can `mvn clean install -pl :<your-module>`.
- Also you don't have to run tests upon each change (ok, maybe you do want to do so, but its your decision).
- If you do run multi module build,  you don't have to run `clean` because when you do, it will remove the `target` folder and recompile the project. If, however you don't run `clean` some modules that don't really have changes maven will recognize that and won't really recompile the module. ---- Other options include `--also-make` option that will filter the modules for the compilation that can be used in conjunction with `-pl` option.

Comment: I have used Spring boot dashboard vscode extension and now things are fine ,I don't need to restart server for any change,In the extension I can just simply click on run ,And it runs the springboot app